# Special symbols break oneboxing in chat

Tags: bug, chat, hyperlinks, onebox

It appears that the onebox (and link-detecting, for that matter) mechanism is broken by special symbols (see [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2470481#2470481)).

For example, the URL `https://stackapps.com/questions/2177/stackexchange™-supercollider-freehand-circle™-editor-now-supported-on-every-s#comment10630_2177` is registered in chat (and on sites) as `https://stackapps.com/questions/2177/stackexchange` (which still works, but doesn't jump to the specified comment).

If you need any more proof than that, look at what it does here:

> [https://stackapps.com/questions/2177/stackexchange™-supercollider-freehand-circle™-editor-now-supported-on-every-s#comment10630_2177](https://stackapps.com/questions/2177/stackexchange%E2%84%A2-supercollider-freehand-circle%E2%84%A2-editor-now-supported-on-every-s#comment10630_2177)

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, when I copy that URL using Chrome, I get `http://stackapps.com/questions/2177/stackexchange%E2%84%A2-supercollider-freehand-circle%E2%84%A2-editor-now-supported-on-every-s#comment10630_2177` - no special characters.

Firefox has the same behavior. So I'm left wondering how you actually managed to end up with that URL in the first place...

That said, if there's a browser out there that's giving you un-escaped URLs in these situations, then the proper solution here is probably to just strip those characters when creating the slug.

Comment: Or delete the slug, so as to just be left with `http://stackapps.com/questions/2177/#comment10630_2177`

Comment: "...just strip those characters when creating the slug." It did that in the past, but I imagine that behaviour made for pretty boring slugs on the language sites.

Comment: Still don't know how Astro even *got* that link, so...

Comment: @Shog9 I just right-clicked and copied the link. It might be something Safari-specific, but it's certainly odd (and I *can* repro it). Is the URL when you're actually visiting the question escaped?

Comment: @AstroCB I just tested on Chrome, Windows 7. When I copied the URL from the question body and pasted it on the address bar, the URL shown was exactly the same; it wasn't escaped. But when I copied the URL from Chrome's address bar, the next time you pasted will already be in escaped-form. However, right-clicking the link and choosing "Copy link address" will also give escaped-form.

Comment: My gut feeling is that this is a safari bug; not seeing anywhere we don't encode the slug properly.

Comment: So are you saying that all browsers that contain unescaped chars like $ and ^ are broken and to use those URIs in chat everyone who creates these URIs should be fixed?

Comment: I'm saying that we're escaping those characters everywhere they would otherwise appear in canonical links, @PlasmaHH - if your browser is *unescaping them*, then that's a bug you should report to your browser vendor.

Comment: @Shog9: I dont think any browsers out there will ever always escape chars like $ and ^ that appear that way in copied URIs, most probably because it is legal for them to be in there and they do not care about single sites not being able to handle that...

Comment: Where did you get $ and ^ from, @plasma? This thread was concerned with non-ascii characters.

Comment: @Shog9: because $ and ^ do seem to be special symbols, and my question about them (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269224) was closed as a duplicate of this one.