# posting links with dollars in chat will not including anything after (and including) the dollar

Tags: bug, chat, markdown, hyperlinks, onebox

This might be a collision with markdown support in chat, but it gets very annoying when you want to post images from e.g. ebay as they almost always contain the dollar sign, e.g.

```
http://i.ebayimg.com/t/00/s/MTAwMFgxMDAw/z/K~IAAOSwMpZUqz7i/$_12.jpg
```

When you post that in chat, the outcome is:

> [i.ebayimg.com/t/00/s/…](http://i.ebayimg.com/t/00/s/MTAwMFgxMDAw/z/K~IAAOSwMpZUqz7i/)$_12.JPG

which is unexpected as well as unusable.

Comment: Some Wolfram Alpha links look bad too: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=BodePlot[+ReplaceAll+[1/(R_1+R_2+C_1+C_2+s^2+%2B+s(R_1+C_1%2BR_1+C_2%2BR_2+C_2)%2B1),+{C_1+-%3E+0.001,+R_1+-%3E+100,+C_2+-%3E+0.000001,+R_2+-%3E+100}+]+]

Comment: It looks to me like those get cut at "^" instead. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fs%5E2 works though. I suspect the problem might be that the web standards dictate these symbols to be %-encoded. But some browsers don't always do that.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff: does ^ have a meaning in markdown? If not, then the markdown collision theory is moot

Comment: Could you instead upload the image to Stack Exchange's server first?

Comment: @MichaelT: I am sure we can find lots of annoying workarounds for all cases where this fails, but whats the point then? Is there a good reason for the URIs to not work properly and people are forced to better always either scan the complete URI manually or feed it through some other mechanism?

Comment: This is an issue of the link parser and one boxer on the chat server. If you aren't one boxing, its always nice to wrap it in a nice `[]()` link for people reading chat. If you are one boxing, its nice to put it on stack exchange's server for places that do things like block ebay at work.

Comment: @MichaelT: I dont know what this boxing is you and the duplicate talk about but well, if its too much to ask for stackexchange to work like every other chat you know and just make links into clickable entities then thats probably a feature

Comment: @PlasmaHH one boxing is when the chat engine takes the link and puts it in a chat box.  Like a post to a SE question, comment, amazon, wikipedia, xkcd, youtube, ... or an image. It does make links into clickable things, but it tries to be smarter about it.

Comment: @MichaelT: It seems a different parser is used for bare URLs vs `[]()`. Because the Wolfram Alpha example also [works with the latter](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=BodePlot[+ReplaceAll+[1/(R_1+R_2+C_1+C_2+s^2+%2B+s(R_1+C_1%2BR_1+C_2%2BR_2+C_2)%2B1),+{C_1+-%3E+0.001,+R_1+-%3E+100,+C_2+-%3E+0.000001,+R_2+-%3E+100}+]+]). And not only in chat but also here in comments.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff yep.  The `[]()` parser is one that works with the chat subset of markdown rather than trying to work with the chat oneboxing feature. Personally, if I can, I like wrapping all links in `[]()` so that the link is more meaningful to other people reading it.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, looks like the chat wants it to be escaped. Until it's fixed, the workaround is to replace the dollar sign in your link with `&#36;`, so as to get:

```
http://i.ebayimg.com/t/00/s/MTAwMFgxMDAw/z/K~IAAOSwMpZUqz7i/&#36;_12.jpg
```

([demo](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4183519#4183519))

Comment: Having to manually fix the URI to be usable in chat is pretty useless, especially with automatically generated URIs and as RespawnedFluff said, it seems to be the case with ^ too. And what other char? It isn't really useful to memorize a list with all the chars and manually replace them, especially not if you are not an everyday chat user ...

Comment: @PlasmaHH Completely agree, this answer is a workaround until it's fixed :)

Comment: Btw, [the useful list of html entities](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html), do you think I memorize them? :D

Comment: looks like its by design and they consider all browsers broken *sigh*